# LOG Issue sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, logarithm

I tried to execute this code :

```
 GDP['LogGdpGwth'] = np.log(GDP['GdpGwth'])
```

I have :
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)

```
X = GDP[['OECDSTInterbkRate']]
y = GDP["LogGdpGwth"]]
```

(No error message here)
and then

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
```

But at this moment I have this error : ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

If I remove one braket :

```
X = GDP["OECDSTInterbkRate"]
y = GDP['LogGdpGwth']
```

no error

then

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
```

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[..................].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

I do not know why, but when I try to execute the non-log GdpGwth, I do not have the issue and I can execute properly the linear regression.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: do you have any zeros or negative values in GdpGwth

Comment: @StupidWolf yes I have negative values and zeros values

Comment: yeah you can't take log of negative values? and if you take log, you get NaN and you cannot regress that

Comment: @StupidWolf so I have to remove all negative values?

Comment: i would guess so. maybe remove it and see how it looks like first. if need be you do a transformation on the data